# Plotting for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I recently got an error on the code that normally worked fine. Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type. So I read online reviews about this error and did conda update pandas since people suggested that there could be incompatibility issues with numy version 1.20.1. Now I get a new error as matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected. How can I get the plot to work.
It is a simple plotting routine from pandas dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'word':wordlist, 'count':countlist})
ax=df1.plot.bar(color='g')
ax.set_xlabel(" word")
ax.set_ylabel("Count") 
pl.suptitle("Year 2012")
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-81ba99f051c4> in <module>
     56 #seri=seri.sort_values('countlist')
     57 
---> 58 ax=df1.plot.bar(color='g')
     59 ax.set_xlabel("Technology word")
     60 ax.set_ylabel("Count")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in bar(self, x, y, **kwargs)
   1001            >>> axes = df.plot.line(
   1002            ...     subplots=True, color={"pig": "pink", "horse": "#742802"}
-> 1003            ... )
   1004 
   1005         .. plot::

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    765     _dataframe_kinds = ("scatter", "hexbin")
    766     _kind_aliases = {"density": "kde"}
--> 767     _all_kinds = _common_kinds + _series_kinds + _dataframe_kinds
    768 
    769     def __init__(self, data):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _get_plot_backend(backend)
   1667             the matplotlib function that is used under the hood.
   1668 
-> 1669         Examples
   1670         --------
   1671         The following examples are generated with random data from

ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback of your error, as that contains valuable information and we can't help without it

Comment: i have included the edited version

Comment: Do you have matplotlib installed? Is this a typo?`pl.suptitle("Year 2012")`